# Any way to bottom-align UILabels with dissimilar fonts?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uilabel

I have an array of UILabels inside the contentView of a custom UITableViewCell.  The font of each label is sized by ranking to form a tag cloud.  In the method that sets up the cell (row), I iterate through the word objects that will fit on that line, setting up the frame for each UILabel as follows:

```
CGRect theFrame = CGRectMake(xPosAdjuster,
    theWordRow.rowHeight - thisWord.lblHeight,
    thisWord.lblWidth,
    thisWord.lblHeight);
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:theFrame];
```

This gets the frames of the labels aligned (see image below), but, unfortunately, the labels have a padding that is a function of the font size.

[image]

Is there any way to remove the padding (border) on a UILabel and/or calculate it exactly so I can adjust the y pos of the frames accordingly?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [this page](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/02/understanding-uifont/). There is information on Apple's Docs, however this was the first I found.

So it looks like you'll have to do some calculation based on the descender of the `UIFont`. You can easily get this value, it is defined as a property on `UIFont`.

Comment: for those of you having issues with the descender, you can edit your font file as described here: http://www.andyyardley.com/2012/04/24/custom-ios-fonts-and-how-to-fix-the-vertical-position-problem/

Answer (score 10):

Here is my final code that lines up the labels:

```
CGRect theFrame = CGRectMake(xPosAdjuster,
    floor(theWordRow.rowHeight - thisWord.lblHeight),
    floor(thisWord.lblWidth),
    thisWord.lblHeight);
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:theFrame];
...
CGRect newFrame = myLabel.frame;
newFrame.origin.y -= floor(myLabel.font.descender);
myLabel.frame = newFrame;
```

[image]

Comment: I think it should be:
newFrame.origin.y += floor(myLabel.font.descender);