# Two auto layouted UILabels with different font sizes: Text bottom alignment

Tags: ios, uilabel, autolayout, text-alignment

this question was asked several times in different contexts but I didn't find a SO Question that solved my specific problem. This one here is the one that asks the same but the answers are "Non-Autolayout"-conform.

[How to align baselines of text in UILabels with different font sizes on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910766/how-to-align-baselines-of-text-in-uilabels-with-different-font-sizes-on-ios)

I layouted my `UILabels` and one `UIImageView` with `NSLayoutConstraints` so that they are bottom aligned (like you see it in the screenshot)

[image]

The `UILabels` and the `UIImageView` have no defined height or width, they automatically adjust their bounds depending on the content.
But you can see that the **"9"** and the **"%"** aren't on the same baseline, even if the labels itselves are bottom aligned. This is because of the different font size.

Methods like `sizeToFit` won't work, because the Labels are already sized by Autolayout so that the content fits automatically.

How can I achieve the bottom alignment with different font sizes? I would prefer no hacks in `layoutSubviews` and other stuff... I like the way how Autolayout works for me but I can't understand why we don't have `NSTextAlignmentBottom` and `NSTextAlignmentTop` in 2013...

Any suggestions or hints?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you used `NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBaseline`? Here's an example of how it lays out `UILabels`:

[image]

I've made this example in the Interface Builder, but it's the same when set up programmatically.

Comment: Wonderful, such a simple answer and the right approach with Autolayouts. I didn't think of the NSLayoutConstraint options... I was too blind to see... thank you!