# Calculate UITextField baseline position

Tags: ios, uitextfield, baseline

I'm trying to programmatically align the baseline of an instance of `UITextField` with an instance of `UIButton`. I'm currently handling this calculation similar way described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542473/any-way-to-bottom-align-uilabels-with-dissimilar-fonts/4543653#4543653), but with `UITextField` there can be an offset to the content. Any ideas how could I get the text position within `UITextField` or even better, is there a more simple way to align the baselines?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, `UITextField` does not actually have any offset around the text, unlike `UIButton`. Regardless, you can figure out the exact text box in both controls:

```
let textField = UITextField()
//... size the field, e.g. textField.sizeToFit()

let button = UIButton()
//... size the button, e.g. button.sizeToFit()

// Compute the target offset between tops (frame.origin.y).
let buttonBox = button.contentRectForBounds(button.bounds)
let buttonBaseline = buttonBox.origin.y + button.titleLabel!.font.ascender

let textFieldBox = textField.textRectForBounds(textField.bounds)
let textFieldBaseline = textFieldBox.origin.y + textField.font!.ascender

let offset = buttonBaseline - textFieldBaseline

//... position button, e.g., button.frame = CGRect(...)

textField.frame = CGRect(
    origin: CGPoint(x: button.frame.maxX, y: button.frame.origin.y + offset),
    size: textField.bounds.size)
```

[image: Example alignment with different font sizes]